# iOS - Tracking Consumable Goods using Apple ID and without Game center Auth

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I would like to keep a track of consumable goods sold against each user but without Auth. I know that Apple asks for a login at the time of IAP for Consumable goods - Apple ID, but what would be the source of identity for the player for keeping a track of consumables without using any form of authentication like Game Center (since the user does login using his apple id for making purchases) but can I derive an identity using the apple id for saving this data?

Comment: You will need to create your own user account system. You have no access to the Apple ID that was used for the purchase

Comment: What could I use to uniquely identify the user apart from the Apple ID on iOS?

Comment: You need to ask them to create some sort of identity on your server. It must be optional though.

Comment: There are some apps in app store which dont ask me to login and still have consumables, do these apps skip tracking the consumable count by skipping the create identity?

Comment: Apple does not require consumable purchases to be available on a user's other devices.  You can track their goods on the device using KeyChain. Many apps choose to allow a user to share their items/balance between devices by allowing them to create an account if they want

Comment: my actual purpose of tracking was actually different, how would you handle the use case of some payer actually purchasing and using consumables and then complaining that he never got them

Comment: If you follow the apple guidelines and only complete the transaction after you have persisted the purchase in your app then that cannot happen unless there is a bug on Apples side and given the volume of purchases that are made, this seems unlikely. You can refer the purchser to ITunes support who can investigate and issue refunds.

Comment: Thanks, I actually meant the case where the consumer intentionally wants to trick you, he actually got the consumables and used them but there is no way for the app developer to justify and say that he did get them because they would neither be tracked on client (as they are already consumed) or server side (assuming only keychain tracking) , do such cases happen and how would Apple or the app developer deal with them?

Comment: The user  can raise a complaint with iTunes support. They can investigate and issue refunds. If a particular app gets a lot of complaints they may contact the developer to investigate. If a particular user raises a lot of complaints they will probably get suspicious and start to deny refunds